# Open a Google Maps link with multiple markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We'd like to open a list of locations in a Google Map link. I've explored many possibilities, but I can't find how to do this.

The map I built using the JavaScript API doesn't show a link to Google Maps with markers on it. I hoped for a "View Larger Map" link like in the Embed API, but none of the variables seemed to add that. I tried the Embed API, but it doesn't take multiple markers.

We need to generate the list dynamically, so MyMaps doesn't work.

The Static Maps API isn't really a Google Map, in that you can't do anything with it.

I tried sending a KML file like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://example.com/j.kml
```

but it looks like Google has discontinued that.

The most promising thing has been the Directions API, but we don't want directions, just a bunch of markers. The URL structure that is showing multiple points is:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Mi+Mero+Mole,+5026+Southeast+Division+Street,+Portland,+OR+97206/3+Doors+Down+Cafe,+Southeast+37th+Avenue,+Portland,+OR/Bunk+Downtown,+211+Southwest+6th+Avenue,+Portland,+OR+97204/@45.5135928,-122.661738,14z/
```

But I tried removing /dir/ to get rid of the directions and Google didn't like that. Has anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: Did you try to interface with Google fusion tables? looks like it's a good fit. Please check this out: https://sites.google.com/site/fusiontablestalks/stories

Comment: Oo, those are beautiful. I'll check them out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My research on the same issue, shows that the directions URL -you have posted- is the most relevant solution at this point.

The only think I could possibly propose as an enhancement, is to leave the starting point blank so the user will be prompted to enter an address as a starting point or automatically enable geolocation by appending the `Current+Location` wording to the url next to `/dir/`:

- [Enable Geolocation](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/Mi+Mero+Mole,+5026+Southeast+Division+Street,+Portland,+OR+97206/3+Doors+Down+Cafe,+Southeast+37th+Avenue,+Portland,+OR/Bunk+Downtown,+211+Southwest+6th+Avenue,+Portland,+OR+97204/@45.5135928,-122.661738,14z/)

> ```
> https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/Mi+Mero+Mole,+5026+Southeast+Division+Street,+Portland,+OR+97206/3+Doors+Down+Cafe,+Southeast+37th+Avenue,+Portland,+OR/Bunk+Downtown,+211+Southwest+6th+Avenue,+Portland,+OR+97204/@45.5135928,-122.661738,14z/
> ```

- [Leave Starting Point Empty](https://www.google.com/maps/dir//Mi+Mero+Mole,+5026+Southeast+Division+Street,+Portland,+OR+97206/3+Doors+Down+Cafe,+Southeast+37th+Avenue,+Portland,+OR/Bunk+Downtown,+211+Southwest+6th+Avenue,+Portland,+OR+97204/@45.5135928,-122.661738,14z/)

> ```
> https://www.google.com/maps/dir//Mi+Mero+Mole,+5026+Southeast+Division+Street,+Portland,+OR+97206/3+Doors+Down+Cafe,+Southeast+37th+Avenue,+Portland,+OR/Bunk+Downtown,+211+Southwest+6th+Avenue,+Portland,+OR+97204/@45.5135928,-122.661738,14z/
> ```